# how to check if the user login and visit specific page first time Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, backend

i'm using laravel and i want to check if the user login and visit this page first time:

this is blade page:

```
     <div class="content">

            <h1>this is the first time to visit this page</h1> //want this heading appears only when user login and visit this page first time
            <h2>Some text here</h2>
            <h2>Some text here</h2>
            <h2>Some text here</h2>
            <h2>Some text here</h2>

      </div>
```

i want the (first heading) above only appears when the user login and visit this page first time, then when he visits this page in another time  or refresh it the (first heading) disappears

Route:

```
 Auth::routes();
 Route::get('/first_time', 'TestmodelController@first_time');
```

Controller:

```
    public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}


public function first_time()
{
    return view('first_time');

}
```

could you help me

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session

Comment: Ok  thanks, how to write statement that check this user login and visit this page first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set session variable on the first visit:

```
public function first_time(Request $request){
    $session = $request->session();
    ($session->has('first_visit')) ? $session->put('first_visit', false) : $session->put('first_visit', true);
    return view('first_time', ['first_visit' => $session->get('first_visit')]);
}
```

inside your blade template:

```
<div class="content">

    @if($first_visit)
    <h1>this is the first time to visit this page</h1>
    @endif
    <h2>Some text here</h2>
    <h2>Some text here</h2>
    <h2>Some text here</h2>
    <h2>Some text here</h2>

</div>
```